# Add 10 days with selected date -on-change method -service now

Tags: datetime, servicenow

I have 2 date fields `issued date` and `due date`.When I choose issued date,due date should be auto populated by adding 10days with selected date. I have written on-change method for this

```
function onChange(control, oldValue, newValue, isLoading, isTemplate) {
   if (isLoading || newValue === '') {
      return;
   }

    //var issuedDate=new GlideDateTime(g_form.getValue('u_issued_date'))
    //var issuedDate=g_form.getValue('u_issued_date')
    alert(issuedDate)
    var gdt = new GlideDateTime(issuedDate);
    gdt.addDays(10)
    g_form.setValue('u_due_date',gdt);
}
```

I am getting an error `GlideDateTime is not defined function ()`.How can I achieve this? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GlideDateTime` is not available on client side. For simple operation like the one you are having you can use javascript `Date` object. Which is pain to format, but doable, example:

```
var date = new Date(g_form.getValue('u_issued_date'));
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 10);  //add 10 days
g_form.setValue('u_due_date', formatDate(date));

function formatDate (date) {
    return date.getFullYear() + '-' +
        leadingZero(date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +
        leadingZero(date.getDate()) + ' ' +
        date.getHours() + ':' +
        date.getMinutes() + ':' +
        date.getSeconds();
}

function leadingZero (value) {
    return ("0" + value).slice(-2);
}
```

For more complicated operation you would wish `GlideDateTime` you will have to use `GlideAjax`, that will do operations on server side, and provide result.